# Price don't change on product page when customer group change (and price different in this group)

Tags: magento2, customer-group, product-prices

I have a strange behavior on a Magento 2.2.10 (but may be it's the same on other version)

I have created 2 more customers groups (G1 and G2), each one with a set of products prices different from normal prices.

The customer fill is cart, then subscribe, and there with a custom field I can change their group on certain conditions.

If condition is ok, the customer changes group (for example G1) and prices (in a `customer_save_before` event).

The cart is updated, the new prices are here, it's working.

BUT !

But if they come back to the product page, the price is still the normal price.

If I logout and then login back (on an incognito window), and go to the product page, now I have the good prices. But if again I change the customer group (to G2 for example), I still have G1 prices on the product I've viewed.

I guess there's a customer cache issue here, but anyone have an idea how to work around this ? I want my caches on.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue, still not resolved. Did you find a solution?

When the incorrect Product Prices are shown, the user must Hard-Refresh in order to see the correct prices .. which is aweful.

Turning off Full Page Caching seems like the only solution ... which is silly.

Comment: @Jagoman Sorry, but no, I haven't. Perhaps finding the request and filter it if there's a varnish cache in front to not be cached ? Or, as you said, turnig of FPC (which is a very bad performance idea unfortunatly)

Comment: I switched the Full Page Cache back from "Varnish Cache" to "Built-in Cache". It resolved the issue. I would prefer Varnish, but hey, FPC is still working.